zero-or-one match is being missed
For an input string like this:
kau(77)j8g(99)sib(88)a21(5)w

I'd like to capture any a or b if it appears before the numbers in parentheses. That is, my desired output is something like:
(["kau(77)" "a" "77"] ["j8g(99)" nil "99"] ["sib(88)" "b" "88"] ["a21(5)" "a" "5"])

but if I use the regex
.*?(a|b)?.*?\((\d+)\)

I miss some of the a and b captures, getting:
(["kau(77)" nil "77"] ["j8g(99)" nil "99"] ["sib(88)" nil "88"] ["a21(5)" "a" "5"])

and if I remove the ? qualifier on the (a|b) I get
(["au(77)" "a" "77"] ["b(88)" "b" "88"] ["a21(5)" "a" "5"])

which has all of the a or b matches, but obviously misses the entire match that includes 99. There will not always be an a or b so I need the {0,1} effect of the ?.
I have resorted to running a second regex on the entire match in order to find any a or b that might be in it, but can this be done with only one regex pass on this one string? Also, I can reproduce everything on this page without the leading .*? on my regex, but my problem seems to have to do with the leading characters of each match, so I've left it on here as a clue.
My unsuccessful single-pass regex is here at regex101.
Beyond the syntax answers here, I asked for an explanation here.

what is the desired outcome for a prefix string that has multiple of a/b; e.g.: kabu(22)?


You can first get the a-b followed by number.
Then, get the other non-a-b part.
Then, pipe it with (.)

([ab])([0-9]+)\(([^\r\n)]*)\)|([^\r\n(]*)\(([^\r\n)]*)\)|(.)

See here.

This is one way to do, and there are other ways, such as:
([ab])([0-9]+)\(([0-9]*)\)|([^\r\n(]*)\(([0-9]*)\)|(.)

See here

([ab])([0-9]+)\(([0-9]*)\): part 1
([^\r\n(]*)\(([0-9]*)\): part 2
(.): part 3


You can also remove those capture groups that you don't want.

Update:
If I understand correctly, you want to write something like:
([^ab\r\n(]*([ab])?[^ab(\r\n]*)\(([0-9]*)\)|(.)

and use something like: ["$1" "$2" "$3"]:
See here

@NankerPhelge Is this what you wanted to do?

No, I'd like to only capture the "a" or "b" and only when it appears. It seems like your first will always capture, say, "kau" and "j8g" when all that I'd like in those two cases is to get "a" and nothing.

@NankerPhelge you only want capture the "a" or "b" and only when it appears: Like this([ab])([0-9]+)\(([0-9]*)\): link? Which language?

At the link in your comment, only the "a" in "a21" is captured. I'd like to also be able to capture the "a" in "kau" earlier in the input string, and so on.

@NankerPhelge See my updates. Also see this.  Is that right?

OK. Yes. (Thanks also for the substitution formatting, but all that I need is the regex.) This works, but now I guess I have a question about the greedy-ness of the preceding operation. You have basically swapped out my .*? in front of the (a|b) for [^ab]*. Why does a non-greedy operation like .*? consume the "a" except at the beginning of the matched string, thus missing the capture of the "a"? obviously, I understand why [^ab]* does not. That seems to be the difference. I'm happy to accept your answer as-is, but I'd love an explanation, too, if you have one.

I should add that I really also need your open parens in that excluded character set, so [^ab(]*, which is still confusing to me. Why must I exclude the ( if I have already asked for non-greedy operations leading up to a (?

@NankerPhelge Your questions has been answered here. You can also accept that answer, which is written cleaner. In short, you're also right. You don't have to do that. I was just trying to make it work. Also, we don't need the dash: ([^ab\r\n(]*([ab])?[^ab(\r\n]*)\(([0-9]*)\)

Assuming there is only one occurrence of a or b to be captured before the digits between parenthesis, you might use 2 capture groups
[^()ab]*([ab])?[^()ab]*\((\d+)\)

The regex matches:

[^()ab]* Match option chars other than parenthesis or a or b
([ab])? Optionally capture either a or b in group 1
[^()ab]*
\((\d+)\) Capture 1+ digits between parenthesis in group 2

See a regex demo.
There is no language listed, but for example in Python using an extra outer capture group to also return the full match with re.findall:
pattern = r"([^()ab]*([ab])?[^()ab]*\((\d+)\))"
s = "kau(77)j8g(99)sib(88)a21(5)w"

matches = re.findall(pattern, s)

print(matches)

Output
[('kau(77)', 'a', '77'), ('j8g(99)', '', '99'), ('sib(88)', 'b', '88'), ('a21(5)', 'a', '5')]

If you want to have a nil value as in the value is missing, you could also use a programming language to check for the group 1 value.
